# angular.js?body=1:9998 Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am novice to angularjs and rails, and i am trying to send json data from rails controller to angularjs controller as follow :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @prods= Product.all.to_json()
  end
end
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ProductApp">
<head>
  <title>Angular2</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'  %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="productsCtrl">
   <%= yield %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

products/index.html.erb

```
<ul ng-repeat= "p in products" >
  <li>{{p.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

productsCtrl.js

```
angular.module("ProductApp", ["ngResource"])
 .controller("productsCtrl", function ($scope, $resource){
  prod = $resource("/products/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}});
   $scope.products= prod.query();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
app.factory('api', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource('', {},
            {
                products: {
                    url: '/products/:id',
                    method: 'POST'
                }
}]);

angular.module("ProductApp", ["ngResource"])
 .controller("productsCtrl", function ($scope, $resource, api){

  api.products({id: {id: "@id"}}, function(result) {
             $scope.products= result;
  }, function(error) {

  });
  $scope.products= prod.query();
});
```

edit:

```
angular.factory('api', ['$resource', function($resource) {

return $resource('', {},
        {
            products: {
                url: '/products/:id',
                method: 'POST'
            }})
 }]);

 angular.module("ProductApp", ["ngResource"])
 .controller("productsCtrl", function ($scope, $resource, api){

   api.products({id: {id: "@id"}}, function(result) {
         $scope.products= result;
   }, function(error) {

 });
  $scope.products= prod.query();
});
```

but still have some errors:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionproductsCtrl.js?body=1:2 (anonymous function)
 angular.js?body=1:9998 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'productsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I try it but still have the same error :/

Comment: thanks, i tried it but i got some other errors so i tried to edit as shown

Comment: theres an extra charecter or a missng one

Comment: by the way prod is not defined anymore maybe thats the problem.